# Refresh the page after adding the item to the array

Tags: reactjs

there is an array with the default value and the item is added to the array using Delta, Table List When a row is added immediately the number of table rows returns to default, why?

App.js

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import {TableData, RegForm} from './Layouts'


class App extends Component {
    state = {
        productList: [
            {id: 11, name: 'CD', price: '2000', describe: 'Educational'},
            {id: 24, name: 'Pen', price: '3500', describe: 'Design'},
            {id: 83, name: 'Pencil', price: '2500', describe: 'Design'}
        ],
    };

    handleDeleteByIndex = index => {
        const product = this.state.productList;
        product.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState({productList: product});
    };

    handleInsertToList = (e) => {
        const product = this.state.productList;
        product.push(e);
        this.setState({productList: product});

    };

    render() {
        const {productList} = this.state;
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <RegForm onInsertRow={this.handleInsertToList}/>
                <TableData rows={productList} onDeleteRow={this.handleDeleteByIndex}/>

            </Fragment>
        );

    }
}

export default App
```

Full code : [enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-inwdg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 2):

The page is refreshing due to the form submission, so everything is reset.

In `Layouts/RegForm.js` you need to prevent the default action of the form:

```
<form
  className={classes.root}
  noValidate
  autoComplete="off"
  onSubmit={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault() // <-- Add this
    props.onInsertRow({
      id: id,
      name: name,
      price: price,
      describe: describe
    });
  }}
>
```

I hope this helps.